# "Помимо формата бумаги A4, разрешается" - наличие запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Помимо формата бумаги A4, разрешается использовать полученный путем складывания его пополам формат A5. Формат A5 удобен тем, что...

Нужна ли запятая после *A4* в первом предложении? *(Я ставлю запятые большей частью интуитивно или ориентирусь на известные мне примеры из "хороших" книг. В английском языке запятая в подобных предложениях непременно ставится. Но, насколько я помню, в русском языке в похожих случаях обходятся без нее.)*

Comment: См. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_565

Comment: Спасибо. Слово "помимо" в моем примере используется в значении "кроме, сверх", и согласно Грамоте допустимы оба варианта, как с запятой, так и без. Но вот есть ли в таких случаях какая-то логика, кроме желания автора создать интонационную паузу, там не сказано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внесу изменения — уберу «складывание формата»:

*Помимо формата бумаги A4, разрешается использовать, полученный делением его пополам, формат A5.*

1. gufo.me›dict/efremova/помимо — ПОМИМО кого-чего, предлог с род. п. 1. Кроме (в 1 знач.), за исключением кого-чего-н.: *П. тебя, ни с кем не говорил. П. всего прочего (кроме того)*. 2. Кроме (во 2 знач.), в добавление к кому-чему-н.: *П. своих детей, растит племянника*.
2. Оборот перед определяемым существительным выделяется запятыми, он осложнён обстоятельственным оттенком значения (благодаря каким условиям?): *Убранный в подполье, урожай обещал сытую зиму*.

Comment: Не согласен, что здесь _обязательно_ требуется выделение запятыми причастного оборота перед определяемым словом. Даже в приведенном Вами примере, скорее всего, пунктуация авторская.

Comment: Да, ваш вариант звучит лучше.

Comment: @trolley813 «Даже в приведенном Вами примере, скорее всего, пунктуация авторская». К пункту 2, видимо, относится... Не проверял, но, как указано на https://orfogrammka.ru/, источником значится Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию / Д.Э. Розенталь, Е.В. Джанджакова, Н.П. Кабанова//РАЗДЕЛ 5 Знаки препинания в предложениях с обособленными членами, § 18.Согласованные определения.10

 

    причастный оборот пунктуация 

версия: 1.1.219

Партнёрская программа
info@orfogrammka.ru © ООО «Орфограмматика», 2012—2021

Comment: @shampar Да, вот [электронная версия справочника](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/81920164.html) (§ 92, пункт 6). Но я, простите, в упор не вижу в предложении о форматах бумаги какого-либо обстоятельственного значения оборота. Ведь формат A5 разрешен для использования не по причине того, что он получается делением пополам формата A4.

Comment: Причину «разрешения» определяют возможностей офисной программы или принтера. Имеет обстоятельственное значение способ получения формата (даётся для представления и понимания — не заучивания).

Comment: _"Причину «разрешения» определяют возможностей офисной программы или принтера."_ — Немного вмешаюсь в ваше обсуждение. _Возможность_ в моем примере определяется руководством фирмы, то есть "если сказано 'делать так', значит 'делай так', а не обсуждай".